# Incorrect results after scanning a file using fscanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have a problem scanning some data from a `.txt` file using `fscanf`.

Example:

`CXKNS87356 John March 136 - Mary Perpetum 419; 8.2.2014. 05:42 3.80257 71.45`

```
typedef struct
{
        char code[12];
        char from[45];
        char to[45];
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        int hour;
        int min;
        float km;
        float price;
    
}Taxi;

while(fscanf(fin, "%[^ \n]%[^-]-%[^;]; %d.%d.", taxi[i].code, taxi[i].from, taxi[i].to, &taxi[i].day, &taxi[i].month)==5)
{
        printf("|%s| |%s| |%s| |%d| ", taxi[i].code, taxi[i].from, taxi[i].to, taxi[i].day);
        i++;
}
```

With this code, I can `fscanf` until I enter `&taxi[i].month`, from there code doesn't work. I need to upload example properly

Comment: `%[^-]` - How much of the string will this match?

Comment: I dont understand, it uploads string for first address (from) until -

Comment: But still i need %d.%d., problem is with dots

Comment: It's just one line of code which needs to be added to accepted answer to remove the last unwanted space. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want for instance :

```
  char restofline[64];
  ...
  while(fscanf(fin, " %11[^ ]%44[^-]-%[^;]; %d.%d.%63[^\n]", taxi[i].code, taxi[i].from, taxi[i].to,
             &taxi[i].day, &taxi[i].month, restofline)==6)
```

because you need to flush the rest of the line `scanf` does not manage in your code

note the space before the first '%' to bypass newline from the previous line, and the fact I limit the size of the string to read to not write out of the arrays

For instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char code[12];
    char from[45];
    char to[45];
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int hour;
    int min;
    float km;
    float price;

}Taxi;

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  Taxi taxi[10];
  char restofline[64];
  
  while(fscanf(stdin, " %11[^ ]%44[^-]-%[^;]; %d.%d.%63[^\n]", taxi[i].code, taxi[i].from, taxi[i].to,
               &taxi[i].day, &taxi[i].month, restofline)==6)
  {
    printf("|%s| |%s| |%s| |%d| \n", taxi[i].code, taxi[i].from, taxi[i].to, taxi[i].day);
    if (++i == 10)
      break;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
CXKNS87356 John March 136 - Mary Perpetum 419; 8.2.2014. 05:42 3.80257 71.45
|CXKNS87356| | John March 136 | | Mary Perpetum 419| |8| 
CXKNS87356 John March 136 - Mary Perpetum 419; 8.2.2014. 05:42 3.80257 71.45
|CXKNS87356| | John March 136 | | Mary Perpetum 419| |8| 
^C
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

And if you want to save all the fields :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char code[12];
    char from[45];
    char to[45];
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int hour;
    int min;
    float km;
    float price;

}Taxi;

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  Taxi taxi[10];
  
  while(fscanf(stdin, " %11[^ ] %44[^-]- %[^;]; %d.%d.%d.%d:%d%f%f",
               taxi[i].code, taxi[i].from, taxi[i].to,
               &taxi[i].day, &taxi[i].month, &taxi[i].year, 
               &taxi[i].hour, &taxi[i].min,
               &taxi[i].km, &taxi[i].price)==10)
  {
    printf("|%s| |%s| |%s| |%d| %d:%d %f %f\n",
           taxi[i].code, taxi[i].from, taxi[i].to, taxi[i].day,
           taxi[i].hour, taxi[i].min, taxi[i].km, taxi[i].price);
    if (++i == 10)
      break;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
CXKNS87356 John March 136 - Mary Perpetum 419; 8.2.2014. 05:42 3.80257 71.45
|CXKNS87356| |John March 136 | |Mary Perpetum 419| |8| 5:42 3.802570 71.449997
CXKNS87356 John March 136 - Mary Perpetum 419; 8.2.2014. 05:42 3.80257 71.45
|CXKNS87356| |John March 136 | |Mary Perpetum 419| |8| 5:42 3.802570 71.449997
^C
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

remark the space still present before the first '%' to bypasss the newline from a line to he next. I also added one to flush space(s) at the beginning of the field 'to', but you need to remove the possible space(s) at the end of the fields 'from' and 'to'

Comment: Why it works if I do this:

while(fscanf(fin, " %[^ \n]%[^-]-%[^;]; %d.", taxi[i].code, taxi[i].from, taxi[i].to,
                 &taxi[i].day)==4)
    {
And if i do code above(i wrote) it doesnt work

Comment: @Momo if you want to get the right parts of the line reading several of them you need to read the end of the line to flush it, look at the execution in my answer, also explaining the interest of the space before the first '%'

Comment: %[^\n] %[^-] - %[^;]; %d.%d.%d. %d:%d %f %[^\n], this full fscanf doesnt work (i upload float price at the end)

Comment: do not start by `"%[^\n]` but by `" %[^ ]` as I do in my answer, do not use `\n` in the first '%..' but only in the last, but when the last field is not a string do not even use '\n' in the last

Comment: Bruno jesi ti nas

Comment: @Momo I edited my answer to save all the fields, look at it (refresh page)

Comment: omg @bruno error was i din't do this i=0 -_-, tnx for help

Answer (score 0):

**You missed the chars which you don't want to read in**:

```
$ grep scanf test2.c 
fscanf(stdin, "%[^ \n] %[^-] - %[^;]; %d.%d.", taxi[i].code, taxi[i].from, taxi[i].to, &taxi[i].day, &taxi[i].month);
$ echo 'CXKNS87356 John March 136 - Mary Perpetum 419; 8.2.2014. 05:42 3.80257 71.45'|./test2
|CXKNS87356| |John March 136 | |Mary Perpetum 419| |8|
```

The | | and the | | after |`-`| were missing.
Example: Your first match is `%[^ \n]` which excludes spaces but you didn't add after that the space which was excluded. Add the space and then your next match `%[^-]` will happen. After that use |`-` | (with space after hyphen).

The only drawback by doing that is the trailing space for John.

**How can you distinguish if a space in the "John field" belongs to that field or is a separator?** I don't think that the scanf parser can handle it. RegEx could. Or you fix the end of `from` by e.g.:

```
$ grep strlen test2.c 
if (taxi[i].from[strlen(taxi[i].from)-1] == ' ') taxi[i].from[strlen(taxi[i].from)-1] = 0;

$ echo 'CXKNS87356 John March 136 - Mary Perpetum 419; 8.2.2014. 05:42 3.80257 71.45'|./test2
|CXKNS87356| |John March 136| |Mary Perpetum 419| |8|
```

By doing that you simply remove the trailing space in "John field".

This is my complete main() method:

```
int main() {
  Taxi taxi[1];
  int i=0;
  // 'CXKNS87356 John March 136 - Mary Perpetum 419; 8.2.2014. 05:42 3.80257 71.45'
  fscanf(stdin, "%[^ \n] %[^-] - %[^;]; %d.%d.", taxi[i].code, taxi[i].from, taxi[i].to, &taxi[i].day, &taxi[i].month);
  if (taxi[i].from[strlen(taxi[i].from)-1] == ' ') taxi[i].from[strlen(taxi[i].from)-1] = 0;
  printf("|%s| |%s| |%s| |%d| \n", taxi[i].code, taxi[i].from, taxi[i].to, taxi[i].day);
  return 0;
}
```

The string

```
CXKNS87356 John March 136 - Mary Perpetum 419; 8.2.2014. 05:42 3.80257 71.45
```

I simply copied from above.

**Note: I ignored year, hour and more like you also did. I assume that you will add parsing of them.**

That means that your first scanf will parse until

```
CXKNS87356 John March 136 - Mary Perpetum 419; 8.2.
```

and your next loop will continue parsing on

```
2014. 05:42 3.80257 71.45\n...
```

If you don't want to parse year and everything after that then simply parse it as a string into a buffer and ignore the content of the buffer.

I assumed that your parsing was missing because you parsed up to month but print only up to day. Hence it looks like work in progress and that the issue was with the spaces.

Comment: I fscanf John March 136 (until -)

Comment: @Momo: You were to fast with your comments. ;-) I was even typing and finally fixing the trailing space at John. :-)

Comment: My code still doesn't work xD, "(SPACE)%[^ ]%[^-]-%[^;]; %d.%d.%d. %d:%d %f %f"

Comment: @Momo I added a note. I just fixed the parse string **for one line**. I assume that you will add parsing for the remaining fields. Otherwise parser will stop after the dot of month and in next loop will take the year from the first input!